# topojson file combination is not opening a new file

Tags: javascript, json, bash, topojson

I have been working through [Mike Bostock's Let's Make a Map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) example.

I am stuck at this step that combines the two json files: `places.json` and `subunits.json` into one file `uk.json` with his following code:

```
topojson \
  -o uk.json \
  --id-property SU_A3 \
  --properties name=NAME \
  -- \
  subunits.json \
  places.json
```

The file `uk.json` is not created in the same directory as `subunits.json` and `places.json`.

I then tried the stdout output code:

```
sudo topojson places.json subunits.json > uk.json
```

Resulting in:   `bash: uk.json: Permission denied`

How to troubleshoot this?